# Custom formula that performs the sum sequentially on a spilled range

Tags: excel-formula

Good afternoon everyone, I have created a custom formula with LAMBDA function that performs a sum of values ​​sequentially, returning the summed values ​​in a spilled range.

```
=LAMBDA(range;s; SUMIFS(range; s;"<="&s ))(C11:C15;E11:E15)
```

[image]

My problem is that to perform the sum as shown in the image, I have to select two ranges: **range of values** ​​to add and the **range of the sequence**. And I need help because the `SUMIFS` function does not allow me to put the `SEQUENCE` function in the ***range_criteria parameter***. I would like my LAMBDA function, just by selecting the range of values ​​to add, to do the same result as the image. I look forward to your help and suggestions.

NOTE:
I've tried doing this and I think it should work, but I'm getting a warning message that there is a problem with the formula.

```
=SUMIFS(C11:C15; SEQUENCE(ROWS(C11:C15)); "<="& SEQUENCE(ROWS(C11:C15)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with this formula:

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE((C11:C15)*(ROW(C11:C15)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C11:C15)))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(C11:C15),1,1,0))
```

In principle, this solution follows the same logic as your SUMIF approach.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, I will use this formula in future occasions with a `Lambda` function. I will accept your answer.